# When Java draws something outside of canvas, will it affect performance?

Tags: java, performance

If I draw something with coordinations like -80 and -90 will it affect performance same way as if it was actually drawn inside?
Is it actually worth it checking if the final image will appear on screen?
(and not drawing it if won't)

Comment: I dint think it will be significant as it wont affect the native device/API, just a few nano seconds of in RAM processing

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*If I draw something with coordinations like -80 and -90 will it affect performance same way as if it was actually drawn inside?*

Somewhat, but not nearly as much as if it is inside the screen.

*Is it actually worth it checking if the final image will appear on screen? (and not drawing it if won't)*

It's practically *never* worth implementing your own culling/clipping in a library where drawing out of bounds isn't an error/access violation, since the library would already have to make that check to avoid writing to memory out of bounds, and it would generally be wise to bet that the library's way of checking this is smart and fast.

So if you were to add your own basic check on top, now you're just making the regular, on-screen drawing perform two of such checks (your own on top of whatever is going on under the hood), and for off-screen cases, it would be likely that your check would actually be slower (or at least no better) than the library's.

Now I have to place emphasis on *basic* culling/clipping here. By basic, I mean checking for each shape you draw on a per-shape basis. There you'll just more likely damage performance.

### Acceleration Structures and Clipping/Culling in Bulk

Yet there are cases where you might have a data structure to do efficient culling of thousands of triangles at once with a single bounding box check to see if it's in the frustum, for example, in a 3D case with structures like bounding volume hierarchies. Games use these types of data structures to massively reduce the amount of drawing requests required per frame with very few checks, and there you do gain a potentially massive performance benefit. A more basic version of this is simply check if the object/mesh containing the triangles has a bounding box that is inside the screen, eliminating potentially thousands of triangles from being culled individually with a single bounding box check.

In 2D with clipping, you might be able to use something like a quad tree or fixed grid to only selectively draw what's on the screen (and also accelerate collision detection or click-detection, e.g.). There you might actually get a performance boost if you can eliminate many superfluous drawing calls with a single check. But again, that's using a data structure that eliminates a boatload of unnecessary drawing calls with a *single check*. These are spatial partitioning structures whose sole point is to avoid checking things on a per-shape basis.

For a more basic 2D example, if you have say, a 2D "widget" which, in order to draw it, involves drawing dozens of different shapes to the screen, you might be able to squeeze a performance gain if you can avoid requesting to draw dozens of shapes with a single check to see if the rectangle encompassing the entire widget is in the screen. Again, there you're doing one check to eliminate many drawing calls. You won't get a performance gain on a level playing field where you're doing that check on a per-shape basis, but if you can turn many checks into a single check, then you have a chance.

Answer (score 4):

According to the Graphics implementation for most common draws/fills (i.e. drawRectangle see: [source of Graphics on grepcode.com](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/awt/Graphics.java#Graphics.drawRect%28int%2Cint%2Cint%2Cint%2) they start with checking if the width and height are bigger then zero and then are doing more operations, therefore doing check for x,y < 0 are in doing the same number of operations in worst case. 
Keep in mind that a rectangle starting at -80 and -90 as you said but width and height i.e. 200 will be displayed on screen.

Answer (score 3):

Yes it will still affect the performance as it still does exist within the program, it's just not visible on the screen

Comment: but it will be less as the IO to native device and screen render wont happen. just some wasted computations.